# Android permissions: Perform task after user pressed "Allow"

Tags: android, android-permissions

I would like to know if there is a way we can identify the event when the user has pressed "Allow" button for contact details access/ calendar access etc.,

I know there is a way to ask for permissions with the ActivityCompat.requestPermissions but is there a way to perform an action right after the user grants a permission?

Comment: Yes. The callback function `onRequestPermissionsResult(..)` which returns the result of the prompt can be used to execute any further code.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First Define the variable:

```
public static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
```

…then use the following code copied from http://web.archive.org/web/20160111030837/http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html —

> request permission using:
>
> ```
> if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
>         android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
>         != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>     // Should we show an explanation?
>     if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
>             android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
>         // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
>         // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
>         // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
>     } else {
>         // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
>         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
>                 new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
> MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
>         // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
>         // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
>         // result of the request.
>     } }
> ```
>
> now catch the result using:
>
> ```
>      @Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
>         String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>     switch (requestCode) {
>         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION : {
>             // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
>             if (grantResults.length > 0
>                 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>                 // permission was granted, yay! Do the
>                 // contacts-related task you need to do.
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
>             } else {
>
>                 // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                 // functionality that depends on this permission.
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             }
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // other 'case' lines to check for other
>         // permissions this app might request
>     } }
> ```

**FOR FRAGMENT**

if you are trying this code in a **`fragment`**, change

`checkSelfPermission()`

to

**`ActivityCompact.checkSelfPermission()`**

and Also change

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`

to

**`requestPermissions()`**

Handling of Permission Result (Allow or Deny) are same as activity.

For a More Complete Example See This [Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057040/android-request-runtime-permission-to-call-action/42057125#42057125)

Comment: Thank you @rafsanahmad007 This is what I was looking for

Comment: Uninstall and clean build apk...make sure to add permission in manifest also...the permission dialog will not show for android version less than marsmallow.

Comment: if grantResults[0]  already == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED?, obviously grantResults.length > 0 so isn't that condition verification redundant?

Comment: ActivityCompact should be ActivityCompat. It's only 1 character, so I can't submit an edit

Answer (score 4):

I used this code for that very purpose.

```
   public boolean isPermissionGranted() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            }, 1);
            return false;
        }
    } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }

}
```

You can then call :

```
    if(isPermissionGranted())
    {
       // do your stuff
    }
```

Comment: It is crashing my app continuously

Answer (score 1):

Call `requestPermissions()` to request the permissions. You find out the result in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` and can determine if they granted the permission or not. That is "right after", from the standpoint of your app's code.