# android request runtime permission to call action

Tags: java, android, permissions, runtime

i have code for call action and i need best way to declare run time permission ive tried many codes but i always get error

here is my basic code any suggestion for make it work with runtime permission
thanks in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button button;
private EditText etPhoneno;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);
    etPhoneno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String phnum = etPhoneno.getText().toString();
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phnum));
                startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this code in your `onClick()` method

```
if(isPermissionGranted()){
     call_action();
}
```

Now, to call create a separate method:

```
public void call_action(){
    String phnum = etPhoneno.getText().toString();
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phnum));
    startActivity(callIntent);
   }
```

Add these two methods for Runtime Permission Checks:

```
 public  boolean isPermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}


 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 1: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                call_action();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
 }
```

Also make sure to add this into the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

**FOR FRAGMENT**

If you are trying this code in a **`fragment`**, change the

`checkSelfPermission()`

to

**`ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()`**

and also change

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`

to

**`requestPermissions()`**

Comment: i use same code but no request appear

Comment: if you are trying this code in a fragment, change         
        `checkSelfPermission(` to `ActivityCompact.checkSelfPermission(` 
                                                and                                                       
        `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(` to `requestPermissions(`   reference : https://stackoverflow.com/q/35989288/2584794