# Update location on google maps when permission is accepted by the android user

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to write an android application which tracks user's location. It works fine when permission is given to the app. I wrote a code piece to check permission and ask for it. But I'm having a problem when permission is given by the user; showing the location at that time. But it works find at the 2nd launch.

```
public class YourLocationActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    String provider;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_location);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        permissionAndLocationUpdate();
    }


    public void permissionAndLocationUpdate() {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 1);
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 5, this);
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 10));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("Your Location"));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1 && grantResults[0] == 0) {
            fetchLastLocation();
        } else {
        }

    }

    private void fetchLastLocation(){
        Task<Location> task = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location loc) {
                if (location != null) {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude())).title("Location"));
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Location recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 10));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("Your Location"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: please refer to [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620466/android-permissions-perform-task-after-user-pressed-allow ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android permissions: Perform task after user pressed "Allow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620466/android-permissions-perform-task-after-user-pressed-allow)

Answer (score 0):

Permission on fragment is a  bit different than activity. Try this. Add this permission on your fragment and check if the permission is enabled or not. Upon enabling the permission, the onRequestPermissionResult block will be called.

```
private final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 102;

public  boolean checkLocation() {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (getActivity().shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Location permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Check this permission before fetching your last location. Hope this helps. Happy Coding